# Nested Max function in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to nest max functions in bigquery.

Sample-

Max(a,Max(b,Max(c,d)))

It is giving an error of invalid arguments. So, what I tried is the Greatest function

Greatest(a,b,c,d). But the issue with Greatest function is that, it will return null if any of the values is null. But What I wanted is that, It should return Greatest value even if any of the values is null.

For Example-

Greatest(1,3,4,null)- It should return 4

Greatest(null,null,null)- It should return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider below scalar subquery since [MAX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#max) aggregate function

> Returns the maximum value of non-NULL expressions. Returns NULL if there are zero input rows or expression evaluates to NULL for all rows. Returns NaN if the input contains a NaN.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 1 a, 3 b, 4 c, null d UNION ALL
  SELECT null, null, null, null
)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(n) FROM UNNEST([a, b, c, d]) n) AS max FROM sample_data;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE()` along with `GREATEST()`:

```sql
SELECT GREATEST(
    COALESCE(a, b, c, d),
    COALESCE(b, a, c, d),
    COALESCE(c, a, b, d),
    COALESCE(d, a, b, c))
FROM yourTable;
```

The above logic behaves such that each of the four values being passed to `GREATEST()` "defers" to some other value in the event that it is `NULL`.  This way, the call to `GREATEST()` will only ever return `NULL` in the event that all four inputs are simultaneously null.

Answer (score 0):

How about below approach?

```
create temp function maxx(x array<int64>)
returns float64 language js as r"""
  return Math.max.apply(null, x);
""";
select *, maxx([a,b,c,d]) as max_value
from your_table
```

with output like below

[image]